# An alternative for getting the size of an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, size

I need an alternative for calling the size of an element with Javascript.

(except `style.width; style.height`)

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need an "alternative"?  What's wrong with the method you have?

Comment: have problems with getting a value different from 0 ... but `offsetHeight` works